# Yoneda Lemma - $\mbox{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G) \simeq G$

Tags: category-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show that for any abelian group $G$, $\\text{Hom}(\\mathbb{Z},G)$ is isomorphic to $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/how-to-show-that-for-any-abelian-group-g-texthom-mathbbz-g-is-isomorp)

Simple question - is it true that $\mbox{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G) \simeq G$ (probably by Yoneda Lemma, which I struggle to understand!)

**Edit**: $G$ is an abelian group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true and much simpler than Yoneda's Lemma: a homomorphism is uniquely determined by its image on 1 $\in \mathbb{Z}$, since 1 generates $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group. By identifying a $\sigma\in \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G)$ with $\sigma(1)\in G$, you get your isomorphism (bijectivity and the fact that this is a group homomorphism follow straight from group axioms).

Comment: Short and simple, thanks!